# Maya 2014 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

I am facing big problem trying to successfully run Maya 2014 on Ubuntu. Yesterday I successfully achieved that goal but today because of graphics driver issues I was forced to reinstall Ubuntu because I messed up system with dodgy graphic drivers for Intel GMA but to the point.

Maya 2014 is made only for rpm based distros so you probably can imagine what I did at first place. Alien of course successfully. Installed generated debs. Fixed som lib dependencies.

I did exactly what I did yesterday but today it is just not working. For now I am installing openSuse alongside Ubuntu and Windows because I just spend loads of time trying to make Maya run on Ubuntu. But anyway I am trying to find better solutions to install Maya on Ubuntu. So if anybody achieved that can you please share the sstep by step solution for this case? I like Ubuntu and I dont want to migrate to openSuse just because of Maya not being made for debian distros. It is shame that they don't made debian package. It isn't so hard to do if I spend half a day to figure out how to run it on debian distro since its linux. Loads of people migrate to linux because of its open source tag and I see that first choice is mostly Ubuntu .I have an experience with openSuse but I just stuck with Ubuntu for long time so going back to openSuse is for me pain but this is my only solution for now. Anyway if somebody can help please help. Loads of people are looking for solution. Internet is flooded with loads of buggy "Easy Install Maya Scripts" for ubuntu and I rather prefer using step by step guide than using scripts that are obsolete at the moment. Problems in running Maya sits in shared object libraries. Thats the main problem that terminal output gave me.

---

```
/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libfam.so.0: cannot open shared           
object file: No such file or directory
```

This is what I've got

Comment: If it is not possible to install it I would suggest running Maya 2014 in RHEL/CentOS through a virtual machine. BTW: could you please share the actual errors you get? Those are most likely the easiest thing for someone to find a fix for.

Answer (score 2):

The `libfam.so.0` shared library is in the `libfam0` package. In the future, you can see which package contains a certain file by running:

```
apt-file search somefilename
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is in gamin, if not look up the rpm package and convert.  I needed it too, and found it in short order.  Also be sure it's in the lib directory, as most of them need to be.  If you have any more issues check the /usr/autodesk/maya2014/support folder and make sure what you need isn't in there first.